# std::string to const char array

Tags: c++, rapidjson

This is the code I am seeking to do

```
std::string json_str;
const char json[] = json_str;
```

this is my try

```
const char json [json_str.size()] = {(char) json_str.c_str ()};
```

But it gives me the error "cast from 'const char*' to 'char' loses precision"

Please help.  Thank you.

Comment: use json_str.c_str() it will return a const char *.

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable length arrays. An array's dimensions must come from a compile-time constant.

Comment: You can't assign directly to an array from an expression that cannot be reduced at compile time.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to `const char*` when you have the string?  If you have a function that takes a `const char*` then just use `json_str.c_str()` as the parameter.

Comment: @NathanOliver I suppose you're right; document.Parse (json_str.c_str()) does compile; now to see if it works or not

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string json_str;
    const char *json = json_str.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should come with at least a short discussion of the lifetime of the buffer pointed to by `json`.

Answer (score 2):

Possible solutions that come to mind:

```
std::string json_str;
const char* json = json_str.c_str();
```

You can use `json` as long as `json_str` is alive.

```
std::string json_str;
const char* json = strdup(json_str.c_str());
```

You can use `json` even after `json_str` is not alive but you have to make sure that you deallocate the memory.